# Enumeration Values As Instances of Objects In Java

Tags: java, enums, wrapper

I have an enumeration that implements an interface.

Currently, each value is defined in the enumeration and an anonymous class is created for each to override the interface methods, eg

```
interface IReceiver {
    void receive(Object o);
}
```

with enum:

```
enum Receivers implements IReceiver {
    FIRST() {
        @Override
        void receive(Object o) { System.out.println(o); }
    },
    SECOND() {
        @Override
        void receive(Object o) { email(o); }
    };
}
```

Instead, I would like to define each value in a separate class, which I instantiate in the enum, but I would prefer not to have to write wrapper methods for each, eg

```
enum Receivers implements IReceiver {
    FIRST(new MyFirstObject()),
    SECOND(new MySecondObject());

    IReceiver receiver;

    Receivers(IReceiver receiver) {
        this.receiver = receiver;
    }

    @Override
    void receive(Object o) {
        receiver.receive(o);
    }
}
```

Is there any easy way to do this. Ideally something like the below would be nice:

```
enum Receivers implements IReceiver {
    FIRST() = new MyFirstObject(),
    SECOND() = new MySecondObject();
}
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated, but I think my second suggestion may be as good as you can achieve in Java.

**edit**
the reason for using an enum, is to provide a clear and easy way to map to single instances of this interface, using a string name

Comment: In Java8 you can make a FunctionalInterface as a constructor parameter.
I don't really see any problem in your solution with IReceiver constructor argument.
I mean, it's just as easy as latter.

Comment: FYI: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Comment: the use of the enum is to make clear that there is only ever one instance of each of these, and to enable mapping to these interfaces instances form strings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may actually not need for your `enum` to implement the interface at all, if I understand the goal of your design.

Instead, you could use a constructor injecting an `IReceiver` the way you do it already in your example.

Then, you either implement the method anonymously, or you have it implemented in your desired concrete class implementing `IReceiver`.

**Example**

```
interface IReceiver {
    void receive(Object o);
}
class MyReceiver implements IReceiver {
    @Override
    public void receive(Object o) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
enum Receivers {
    // anonymous
    FIRST(
        new IReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void receive(Object o) {};
        }
    ), 
    // concrete
    SECOND(new MyReceiver());

    IReceiver receiver;

    Receivers(IReceiver receiver) {
        this.receiver = receiver;
    }

    public IReceiver getReceiver() {
        return receiver;
    }
}
```

Comment: are you suggesting that I then access these interface instances via the field?

Comment: for example, providing a getter?

Comment: that would work, by preventing the need of wrapping each method, although it does make accessing the values of the enumeration more difficult

Comment: @JoshBambrick yes, exactly. Forgot to add a getter in the code, fixing now. It would not change the accessibility of the enumeration values, but it would be slightly heavier syntactically, as you'd need to invoke the getter on the values.

Comment: in my particular offline example, this solution does make a lot of sense, since I am already using a getter to return a value from a string, and I can just modify that to return a field of the enum value